# Create An Associative Array In PHP From MySQL With Duplicate Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, associative-array

I have a MySQL Database with a table called users in it I need to make into an array. But it has to be able to handle duplicate values.

When it finds duplicate values, it joins the values under one key. I only need this joining of the values in the user_id column though, since this is going to be an eCommerce site, and people can purchase more than one item at a time.

This is what my database looks like, specifically the table called queue:

```
Table Queue:
user_id, item_id
100, 103850
100, 103850
100, 129374
101, 303213
101, 103850
```

I need it though, to return an array that looks something like this:

```
    array(
    100 => array(
        'items' => array(
            array('item_id' => 103850),
            array('item_id' => 103850),
            array('item_id' => 129374),
        ),
    ),
    101 => array(
        'items' => array(
            array('item_id' => 303213),
            array('item_id' => 103850),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now this is the code I am using right now, which I got from another question I asked before, but it didn't really answer my question in full.

```
<?php

function getAllUsers() {
    $data_from_db = array(
        100 => array(
            'items' => array(
                array('item_id' => 103850),
                array('item_id' => 103850),
                array('item_id' => 129374),
            ),
        ),
        101 => array(
            'items' => array(
                array('item_id' => 303213),
                array('item_id' => 103850),
            ),
        ),
    );

    // while loop fetch to array blah blah

    $users = $data_from_db;
    return $users;
}

if(isset($_GET['jsoncallback'])) {
    $data = getAllUsers();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

?>
```

What’s wrong with the code above is that it is manually entered into the PHP script, and is not generated using the MySQL query. I want it to generate using the MySQL query, but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do so.

Comment: that was my example yesterday :), you just need a simple select on db, i just used that dummy data as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just do a simple query. Follow this example:

```
function getAllUsers() {
    $data = array();
    // host - username - password - database
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test');
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT `user_id`, `item_id` FROM `table_queue`');
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$row['user_id']]['items'][] = array('item_id' => $row['item_id']);
    }
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_GET['jsoncallback'])) {
    $data = getAllUsers();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

?>
```

When you call `http://yoursite.com?jsoncallback`, you get something like this:

> **`{"100":{"items":[{"item_id":"103850"},{"item_id":"103850"},{"item_id":"129374"}]},"101":{"items":[{"item_id":"303213"},{"item_id":"103850"}]}}`**

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This really did help me with my site.

Answer (score 0):

I pressume you'd fetch your sql data something like this pseudo code:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Giving you something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [100] => 103850
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [100] => 103850
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [100] => 129374
        )
......etc

)
```

Allowing something like the following:

```
        $data = array();

        foreach ($sql as $item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $val) {
                if (!isset($data[$key][$val])) {
                    $data[$key][] = array('item_id' => $val);
                }
            }
        }
```

Rendering:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 103850
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 103850
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 129374
                )

        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 303213
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 103850
                )

        )

)
```

To be honest; this probably isn't the best way to go about this. You would most likely go with something like the other answers with the conditional if statement to check and set to their respective arrays.